# HTML Form automatically send JSON object to API

Tags: html, json, automation

I have an online form from Formstack that I put on a website, and the code for the form is in HTML. However, I need to set it up so that whenever someone submits information through the form, automatically the form will send me the information (already set up) and then send the information in JSON to an API from Trulioo. The API is supposed to let me know the results.

I do not have a lot of experience in coding, but I do know that this would require some interesting code in order to make this system automated.

Can anyone help?

Here is a part of the form's code:

```
<div id="fsRow2312547-2" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow">
<div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical    
fsSpan100" id="fsCell40879974" lang="en">
<span id="label40879974" class="fsLabel fsRequiredLabel">Name<span   
class="fsRequiredMarker">*</span></span>
<div class="fsSubFieldGroup">
<div class="fsSubField fsNameFirst">
<input type="text" id="field40879974-first" name="field40879974-first" 
size="20" value="" required class="fsField fsFieldName fsRequired" aria-
required="true" />
<label class="fsSupporting fsRequiredLabel" for="field40879974-first">First 
Name<span class="hidden">*</span></label>
</div>
<div class="fsSubField fsNameLast">
<input type="text" id="field40879974-last" name="field40879974-last" 
size="20" value="" required class="fsField fsFieldName fsRequired" aria-
required="true" />
<label class="fsSupporting fsRequiredLabel" for="field40879974-last">Last 
Name<span class="hidden">*</span></label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="fsRow2312547-3" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow">
<div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical 
fsSpan100" id="fsCell40879975" lang="en">
<label id="label40879975" class="fsLabel fsRequiredLabel" 
for="field40879975">Address<span class="fsRequiredMarker">*</span>                        
</label>
<label for="field40879975-address" class="hidden">Address Line 1<span 
class="fsRequiredMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="field40879975-address" name="field40879975-address" 
size="50" required value="" class="fsField fsFieldAddress fsRequired" aria-
required="true" />
<input type="text" id="field40879975-address2" name="field40879975-address2" 
size="50" value="" style="margin-top:5px;" class="fsField fsFieldAddress2" 
/>
<div class="fsSubFieldGroup">
<div class="fsSubField fsFieldCity">
<input type="text" id="field40879975-city" name="field40879975-city" 
size="15" value="" required class="fsField fsFieldCity fsRequired" aria-
required="true" />
<label class="fsSupporting" for="field40879975-city">City</label>
</div>
```

From there Formstack (the online form company) uses some code to send the inputted information. I need it to be in JSON format like this:

```
{
  "AcceptTruliooTermsAndConditions": true,
  "Demo": true,
  "ConfigurationName": "sample string 4",
  "ConsentForDataSources": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
  ],
  "CountryCode": "sample string 5",
  "DataFields": {
    "PersonInfo": {
      "FirstGivenName": "sample string 1",
      "MiddleName": "sample string 2",
      "FirstSurName": "sample string 3",
      "SecondSurname": "sample string 4",
      "ISOLatin1Name": "sample string 5",
      "DayOfBirth": 1,
      "MonthOfBirth": 1,
      "YearOfBirth": 1,
      "MinimumAge": 1,
      "Gender": "sample string 6",
      "AdditionalFields": {
        "FullName": "sample string 1"
      }
    },
    "Location": {
      "BuildingNumber": "sample string 1",
      "BuildingName": "sample string 2",
      "UnitNumber": "sample string 3",
      "StreetName": "sample string 4",
      "StreetType": "sample string 5",
      "City": "sample string 6",
      "Suburb": "sample string 7",
      "County": "sample string 8",
      "StateProvinceCode": "sample string 9",
      "Country": "sample string 10",
      "PostalCode": "sample string 11",
      "AdditionalFields": {
        "Address1": "sample string 1"
      }
    },
    "Communication": {
      "MobileNumber": "sample string 1",
      "Telephone": "sample string 2",
      "EmailAddress": "sample string 3"
etc
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please add more information.

Comment: SO is to help you fix your code, not to make your code. :)

Comment: I added some things that show what I am talking about. Thank you

Comment: I understand. Could someone push me in the right direction? I just don't know where to start, and I have never written in Java before.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Javascript file containing some code that will look like the following...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var foo = $("#foo");
  
  foo.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var jsonData = {
      "bar":$("#bar").value(),
      "stuff":"another field needed by API"
    };
    
    $.ajax({
      url : 'http://path.to/api/url',
      dataType : 'json',
      contentType : 'application/json;',
      data : jsonData,
      type : 'POST',
      complete : handleData
    });
    
    function handleData(data) {
      console.log(data);
      // do whatever with response data
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" />
  <input type="submit" name="baz" id="baz" />              
</form>
```

You'll need to clarify the requirements and maybe do a lot more research with web programming...